# Identify two rows with 1 year or more of difference

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table called finance that I store all payment of the customer. The main columns are: ID,COSTUMERID,DATEPAID,AMOUNTPAID.

 What I need is a list of dates by COSTUMERID with dates of its first payment and any other payment that is grater than 1 year of the last one. Example:

```
+----+------------+------------+------------+
| ID | COSTUMERID |  DATEPAID  | AMOUNTPAID |
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|  1 |          1 | 2015-01-10 |         10 |
|  2 |          1 | 2016-01-05 |         30 |
|  2 |          1 | 2017-02-20 |         30 |
|  3 |          2 | 2016-03-15 |        100 |
|  4 |          2 | 2017-02-15 |        100 |
|  5 |          3 | 2017-05-01 |         25 |
+----+------------+------------+------------+
```

What I expect as result:

```
+------------+------------+
| COSTUMERID |  DATEPAID  |
+------------+------------+
|          1 | 2015-01-01 |
|          1 | 2017-02-20 |
|          2 | 2016-03-15 |
|          3 | 2017-05-01 |
+------------+------------+
```

Costumer 1 have 2 dates: the first one + one more that have more then 1 year after the last one.

I hope I make my self clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just want `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(datepaid) over (partition by customerid order by datepaid) as prev_datepaid
      from t
     ) t
where prev_datepaid is null or
      datepaid > dateadd(year, 1, prev_datepaid);
```

Comment: I made some few modifications but the base was your solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Gordon's solution is correct, as long as you are only looking at the previous row (previous payment) diff, but I wonder if Antonio is looking for payments greater than one year from the last 1 year payment, in which case this becomes a more complex problem to solve. Take the following example:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (
     CustomerID smallint 
    ,DatePaid date
    ,AmountPaid smallint )

INSERT INTO #Test
SELECT 1, '2015-1-10', 10
INSERT INTO #Test
SELECT 1, '2016-1-05', 30
INSERT INTO #Test
SELECT 1, '2017-2-20', 30
INSERT INTO #Test
SELECT 1, '2017-6-30', 50
INSERT INTO #Test
SELECT 1, '2018-3-5', 50
INSERT INTO #Test
SELECT 1, '2018-5-15', 50
INSERT INTO #Test
SELECT 2, '2016-3-15', 100
INSERT INTO #Test
SELECT 2, '2017-6-15', 100

WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 
         CustomerID
        ,DatePaid
        ,LAG(DatePaid) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY DatePaid) AS PreviousPaidDate
        ,AmountPaid
    FROM #Test )

SELECT 
     *
    ,-DATEDIFF(DAY, DatePaid, PreviousPaidDate) AS DayDiff
    ,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, PreviousPaidDate, DatePaid)  >= 365 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Paid 
FROM CTE
```

Row number 5 is > 1 year from the last 1 year payment, but subtracting from previous row doesn't address this. This may or may not matter but I wanted to point it out in case that is what he means.